# Multiprocessing pause 1 code while the other is active?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyautogui

I'm making a bot for a clicker game, the game has ads that pop up at random times. With the code below these pop-ups get dismissed whenever they're detected. However, the code that plays the clicker game is timed and whenever an ad is found, it messes with the code, making the program fail.
Does anyone know something to pause what happens in play() whenever ad() finds something?

My code:

```
from pyautogui import * 
import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
import win32api, win32con
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

def ad():
    adloop = True
    while adloop:
        cross = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.95)        
        if cross != None:
            print("Popup!")
        else:
            print("Checking for popups...")

def count():
    amount = 0
    count = True
    while count:
        amount += 1
        print(amount)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__=='__main__':
        p1 = Process(target = ad)
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(target = count)
        p2.start()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It'd be a lot easier to help if you showed a minimal version of the problematic behavior. The commented out stubs are important, as is the behavior in the game. Thanks. By the way, do you really need MP for this or would multithreading be sufficient? It's easier to share state in threading, and I figure most of  the I/O is blocking waiting on sleeps and whatever you're using to interact with wherever the clicker game is (hint: add more concrete details, please).

Comment: The code I made is 200> lines now, I don't think pasting all that here is the way SO works, or is it? The program works besides the fact that popups cause my automated clicks to get interrupted, and it makes the program fail. 
The way I'm making the program click on different things is with pyautogui.

Comment: Whoops -- I forgot to share the link: [mcve]. From that link: "Streamline your example ....

    Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem." You probably don't even need the cookie clicker, just two processes that exhibit the problematic behavior under certain conditions -- you can "simulate" an ad or cookie acceptance banner event manually, for the purposes of demonstration. Just take care not to oversimplify so you can extrapolate responses you get back to your original problem.

Comment: I made a minimized program that detects the code, while the other process is counting +1 every second. Whenever there is a popup that gets checked by program 1, program 2 should stop counting. Where can I share It?

Comment: In the post, please. I should be able to copy/paste, run the code without having to mess with anything, see the problem, then write solution (if I know of one).

Comment: It's in there now, to make it work there should be an image with image.png in the same folder as the code. The idea is that count() counts while there is no image, and when there is an image, it stops counting. If the image gets removed the process has to continue where it left off.
Already thank you for assisting me, and thank you in advance!

Comment: @Bramsko FYI, pretty good [mcve].  I got it working, but for future refeference remove unneeded imports and mention any required 3rd party modules.  I had to install pyautogui (obvious), pillow, and opencv-python to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Process.Event` as a flag.

Note that `pip install pyautogui pillow opencv-python` is needed for operation.

```py
import pyautogui
import time
from multiprocessing import Process,Event

def ad(e):
    adloop = True
    while adloop:
        cross = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.95)
        if cross != None:
            print("Popup!")
            e.clear()
        else:
            print("Checking for popups...")
            e.set()

def count(e):
    amount = 0
    while True:
        e.wait()  # sleep process when event is clear.
        amount += 1
        print(amount)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Create an event to share between the processes.
    # When set, the counting process will count.
    e = Event()
    e.set()

    # Make processes daemons, so exiting main process will kill them.
    p1 = Process(target = ad, args=(e,), daemon=True)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = count, args=(e,), daemon=True)
    p2.start()
    input('hit ENTER to exit...')
```

Output:

```
hit ENTER to exit...1
Checking for popups...
2
Checking for popups...
Checking for popups...
3
Checking for popups...
4
Checking for popups...
Popup!
Popup!
Popup!
Popup!
Popup!
Popup!
Popup!
Popup!
Checking for popups...
5
Checking for popups...
6
Checking for popups...
Checking for popups...
7
```

Comment: Thanks! Would this work if the code gets send to multiple defs in def count(e)? The not-minimized code is a lot bigger and uses multiple defs. (I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: @Bramsko it’s up to you to poll the event often enough to make it responsive. You can call anything you want in the `while e.is_set()` loop.

Comment: @Bramsko Also, anywhere you call `e.wait()` will put the process to sleep if the event is not set, but will do nothing if set.  So the code would work skipping deleting the `while e.is_set():`.  It would wait anytime the event is cleared.  Place those in your code at safe places to pause processing when the ad is up.

Comment: @Bramsko Tested and updated code to eliminate `while e.is_set():`.

Comment: @Bramsko Correct, when `e` is set `e.wait()` won't wait.  if `e` is clear `e.wait()` will sleep until it is set again.